# Relationship between a distribution function and the truncated distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $F(x)$ be a distribution function and $G(x)$ be $F(x)$ truncated on some interval $(a,b)$. I want to show that:

$$G(x)=\frac{F(x)-F(a)}{F(b)-F(a)}, a<x \leq b$$

I want to do this by using conditional probabilities. I know that

$$ G(x)=Pr(X\leq x \mid a<X \leq b) = \frac{Pr(a<X \leq b \mid X \leq x)}{Pr(a<X<b)}*Pr(X \leq x) $$

It seems to me that I have to argue that

$$Pr(a<X \leq b \mid X \leq x)*Pr(X \leq x)=Pr(a<X \leq x) $$

How can I do that?

Comment: It is (almost) the definition so needs no argumentation. RHS must be changed into $Pr(a<X\leq x)$. Secondly I would advice you to abbreviate on $(a,b]$ instead of $(a,b)$. This to avoid troubles at $b$

Comment: The most universal way to define $P\left(A\mid B\right)$ is just
to state that it must satisfy $P\left(A\mid B\right)P\left(B\right)=P\left(A\cap B\right)$.
If $P\left(B\right)>0$ then this is equivalent with $P\left(A\mid B\right)=\frac{P\left(A\cap B\right)}{p(B)}$.

Comment: If $a \lt x \le b$ then $\Pr(a\lt X\le b \mid X \leq x) = \Pr(a\lt X\le x \mid X \leq x) = \dfrac{F(x)-F(a)}{F(x)}$

Comment: I agree on your suggestions about b. The problem is found in a textbook (Bølviken, Camebridge), but it surely is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

$ G(x)=Pr(X\leq x|a<X\leq b) = Pr(X\leq x, a<X\leq b) /Pr(a<X\leq b) = Pr(a<X\leq x) / Pr(a<X\leq b)$

Now numerator is simplify as $ F(x)-F(a) $. Denominator is  $F(b)-F(a)$. That's the answer.